# Efficient C++ Resource Manager

Tags: c++, pointers, opengl

This is my final attempt of making an efficient `ResourceManager` class, which takes care of allocating OpenGL objects (like Shader, Textures, Meshes, ...). It stores each resource in a `unique_ptr` and then distributes `const` pointers of that type, which I call "Observant pointers." They cannot be deleted because resource allocation is only done via the `ResourceManager` class.

**ResourceManager.h**:

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include "../render/Shader.h"
#include "../render/Mesh.h"
#include "../render/Texture.h"

namespace Spiky
{

class ResourceManager
{
    public:

        using ShaderRepo = std::unordered_map<const char*, std::unique_ptr<CShader>>;
        using MeshRepo = std::unordered_map<const char*, std::unique_ptr<CMesh>>;
        using TextureRepo = std::unordered_map<const char*, std::unique_ptr<CTexture>>;

        //Shader
        static const CShader* LoadShader(const char* ID, const char* vs, const char* fs)
        {
            shaderObjects.insert(std::pair<const char*, std::unique_ptr<CShader>>(ID, std::make_unique<CShader>(
                                                                                      (shaderRootDir + std::string(vs)).c_str(),
                                                                                      (shaderRootDir + std::string(fs)).c_str())));
            return (shaderObjects.at(ID).get());
        }

        static const CShader* LoadShader(const char* ID, const char* vs, const char* fs, const char* gs)
        {
            shaderObjects.insert(std::pair<const char*, std::unique_ptr<CShader>>(ID, std::make_unique<CShader>(
                                                                                      (shaderRootDir + std::string(vs)).c_str(),
                                                                                      (shaderRootDir + std::string(fs)).c_str(),
                                                                                      (shaderRootDir + std::string(gs)).c_str())));
            return (shaderObjects.at(ID).get());
        }

        static CShader* GetShader(const char* ID)
        {
            return (shaderObjects.at(ID).get());
        }

        //Mesh
        static const CMesh* LoadMesh(const char* ID, Vertex* vertices, unsigned int numVertices, unsigned int* indeces, unsigned int numIndices)
        {
            meshObjects.insert(std::pair<const char*, std::unique_ptr<CMesh>>(ID, std::make_unique<CMesh>(
                                                                                  vertices,
                                                                                  numVertices,
                                                                                  indeces,
                                                                                  numIndices)));
            return (meshObjects.at(ID).get());
        }

        static const CMesh* LoadMesh(const char* ID, const char* fileName)
        {
            meshObjects.insert(std::pair<const char*, std::unique_ptr<CMesh>>(ID, std::make_unique<CMesh>(
                                                                                  (meshRootDir + std::string(fileName)).c_str())));
            return (meshObjects.at(ID).get());
        }

        //Texture
        static const CTexture* LoadTexture(const char* ID, const char* texturePath, GLenum texTarget = GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLfloat filter = GL_LINEAR,
            GLfloat pattern = GL_REPEAT, GLenum attachment = GL_NONE)
        {
            textureObjects.insert(std::pair<const char*, std::unique_ptr<CTexture>>(ID, std::unique_ptr<CTexture>(new CTexture(
                (textureRootDir + std::string(texturePath)).c_str(), texTarget, filter, pattern, attachment))));
            return (textureObjects.at(ID).get());
        }

        static const CTexture* LoadTexture(const char* ID, int width, int height, unsigned char* data = nullptr, GLenum texTarget = GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            GLfloat filter = GL_LINEAR, GLfloat pattern = GL_REPEAT, GLenum attachment = GL_NONE)
        {
            textureObjects.insert(std::pair<const char*, std::unique_ptr<CTexture>>(ID, std::unique_ptr<CTexture>(new CTexture(
                width, height, data, texTarget, filter, pattern, attachment))));
            return (textureObjects.at(ID).get());
        }

        static const CTexture* LoadTextureCustomPath(const char* ID, const char* texturePath, GLenum texTarget = GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLfloat filter = GL_LINEAR, GLfloat pattern = GL_REPEAT, GLenum attachment = GL_NONE)
        {
            textureObjects.insert(std::pair<const char*, std::unique_ptr<CTexture>>(ID, std::unique_ptr<CTexture>(new CTexture(
                texturePath, texTarget, filter, pattern, attachment))));
            return (textureObjects.at(ID).get());
        }

        static const* CTexture GetTexture(const char* ID)
        {
            return (textureObjects.at(ID).get());
        }



    private:
        static ShaderRepo shaderObjects;
        static MeshRepo meshObjects;
        static TextureRepo textureObjects;
        static std::string shaderRootDir;
        static std::string meshRootDir;
        static std::string textureRootDir;
    };
}
```

**ResourceManager.cpp**:

```
#include "../core/ResourceManager.h"

namespace Spiky
{
    ResourceManager::ShaderRepo ResourceManager::shaderObjects = ShaderRepo();
    ResourceManager::MeshRepo ResourceManager::meshObjects = MeshRepo();
    ResourceManager::TextureRepo ResourceManager::textureObjects = TextureRepo();
    std::string ResourceManager::shaderRootDir = std::string("assets/shaders/");
    std::string ResourceManager::meshRootDir = std::string("assets/models/");
    std::string ResourceManager::textureRootDir = std::string("assets/images/");
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30988/discussion-on-question-by-mattmatt-efficient-c-resource-manager).

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Well, your choice of backing-type for your collections of shaders, meshes and textures has a few *interesting* results:

   Your keys are pointers, not strings, and those pointers are compared/hashed.
   While the compiler *may* freely merge string-literals, it *need not*.
   Every self-respecting compiler in practice does it inside a single translation-unit, but outside that it fast becomes less common to never done.

   There are two ways to resolve that, depending on your goals:

   - Change the key-type to `std::string`. That's the easiest and most versatile solution, but it has the disadvantage of a potential additional allocation.
   - Change the hash and comparison-algorithm used by the collection to treat the pointers as representing the string-value they point to. The disadvantage is that *you* must make sure the strings don't change until the manager releases the entry.
2. Looking at `Load@`, while those functions are all short, there are loads of things to optimize:

   - There's `std::make_pair(...)` when needed.
   - One can directly concatenate a c-style string and a `std::string`, no need for an additional temporary object.
   - You can use `std::emplace` to avoid uselessly creating a `std::pair`.
   - `insert` and `emplace` already return an iterator to the inserted element, or whatever prevented insertion, and a `bool` to indicate what happened.
   - If you allow for the element already being in the collection, recreating it just to destroy it is a huge waste.

   ```
   template<class T>
   static const CShader* LoadShader(T&& ID, const char* vs, const char* fs) {
       auto res = shaderObjects.emplace(std::forward<T>(ID));
       if(res.second)
           try {
               res.first->second = std::make_unique<CShader>((shaderRootDir + vs).c_str(),
                   (shaderRootDir + fs).c_str());
           } catch(...) {
               shaderObjects.erase(res.first);
               throw;
           }
       return res.first->second.get();
   }
   ```

As an aside, I have no idea why you used typedefs for your collections...
As far as I can see, they are useless.

Also, you know you could use `struct`?

---

Things get far more efficient if you have a C++17 standard-library (and thus access to [`try_emplace(...)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/try_emplace):

```
 return &shaderObjects.try_emplace(ID, (shaderRootDir + vs).c_str(),
     (shaderRootDir + fs).c_str()).first->second;
```

If you don't, but can arrange for `CMesh`, `CTexture` and `CShader` to be efficiently default-constructible and either swappable or move-assignable, that is also sufficient.

In a pinch, if your default-constructor is lightweight and cannot throw, you could even use explicit destructor-call and placement-new. That isn't nice, but it's efficient enough and it works:

```
template<class T>
static const CShader* LoadShader(T&& ID, const char* vs, const char* fs) {
    auto res = shaderObjects.emplace(std::forward<T>(ID));
    if(res.second)
        try {
            res.first->second.~CShader(); // noexcept
            new((void*)&res.first->second) CShader((shaderRootDir + vs).c_str(),
                (shaderRootDir + fs).c_str());
        } catch(...) {
            new((void*)&res.first->second) CShader(); // efficient and noexcept
            shaderObjects.erase(res.first);
            throw;
        }
    return &res.first->second;
}
```

In that case, they should be directly in the map, as elements in a `std::unordered_map` stay exactly where they are until they are erased, meaning we have one dynamic allocation less.

Comment: Thank you : ) One more thing : do you think it is good practise to return a raw pointer  ?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it, in the right situation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23016883/3204551